# Function return false values in c++

Tags: c++

I'm playing in Codingame with c++. I only have an intermediate level in c++.

the problem that I encountered was that I have to call a function twice in order to get the right value from it :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

long double dist(long double phi1,long double lam1,long double phi2,long double lam2){
    phi1 *= M_PI/180;
    phi2 *= M_PI/180;
    lam1 *= M_PI/180;
    lam2 *= M_PI/180;
    long double R{(pow( (phi1-phi2)*cos(lam1 + (lam2-lam1)/2) ,2)  +  pow(lam1 - lam2 , 2))} ;
    return R;
}
long double formatting(string n){ //the values contain a ',' instead of '.'
    long double M{0};
    int comma{0};
    for(char num: n){
        if (num ==','){
            comma += 1;
        } else{
            if (comma){
                M += atoi(&num)/(pow(10,comma));
                comma += 1;
            }else{
                M *= 10;
                M += atoi(&num);
            }
        }
    }
    return M;
}

int main(){   
    long double min_distance{9999999999999};
    string min_name{"None"};
    string LON;
    cin >> LON; cin.ignore();
    string LAT;
    cin >> LAT; cin.ignore();
    int N;
    cin >> N; cin.ignore();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        string id{};
        string name{};
        string add{};
        string tel{};
        string phi{};
        string lam{};

        getline(cin, id,';');
        getline(cin, name,';');
        getline(cin, add,';');
        getline(cin, tel,';');
        getline(cin, phi,';');
        getline(cin, lam);
        if (min_distance >= dist(formatting(LON),formatting(LAT) ,formatting(phi),formatting(lam)) ){
            // min_distance = dist(formatting(LON),formatting(LAT) ,formatting(phi),formatting(lam));
            // dist(formatting(LON),formatting(LAT) ,formatting(phi),formatting(lam));
            min_distance = dist(formatting(LON),formatting(LAT) ,formatting(phi),formatting(lam));
            min_name = name;
        }
    }
    cout << min_name << endl;
    cerr <<"The min distance: "<<min_distance<<endl;
}
```

if I uncomment one of the lines :

```
            // min_distance = dist(formatting(LON),formatting(LAT) ,formatting(phi),formatting(lam));
            // dist(formatting(LON),formatting(LAT) ,formatting(phi),formatting(lam));
```

I get exactly the right value that I want (I mainly have problems with the value 0)

the wrong output :

```
cerr : The min distance: 1.25967e-07
cout : Maison de la Prevention Sante
```

the right output :

```
cerr : The min distance: 0
cout : Cimetiere Saint-Etienne
```

Instead of giving you any other output, you can directly go and try it in the website : https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/defibrillators

Thanks

Comment: We'd like a clear question rather than a link to some game you are playing.

Comment: [`atoi(&num)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) will not do what you think it does, because it expects a nul-terminated character string. Taking the address of a character does not make a string.

Comment: "_Instead of giving you any output, you directly go and try it in the website_" - No, instead of us going to an external site to figure out what the expected output is and what you get instead, why don't you provide all the info needed in the question?

Comment: `long double formatting(string n){ //the values contain a ',' instead of '.'` -- What is the goal of this function?  Is it simply to remove commas from the string and return a double?  If it is, you don't need to write all of this code using `pow` and whatever else you have there, including making mistakes using `&num`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the formatting function only does that.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Do you have an alternative please ?

Comment: Then you do know that you could simply call `remove()` and `erase`, and just return the number as a double?  None of these incomprehensible loops needed to be coded.  If you had done that, maybe that solves the problem?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't see exaclty how I can do that

Comment: @MustaphaAJEGHRIR [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ada2d89b136c5bdb).  You should break down a program into individual sections, and write small programs first.  If the goal is to remove characters from a string, or any value from a container, C++ has a wealth of functions to do that -- there is no need to write `for` loops to do that job.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie